# DisplayLeakActivity does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, leakcanary, android-studio-2.2

Since a while I have problems with LeakCanary (I think since Android Studio 2.2 but not sure)

I added it with this dependencies

```
 dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
 }
```

When I click on the play button in Android Studio I get this error message:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.debug/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.debug/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.debug/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.debug/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

But when I open the apk file with [ClassyShark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark) I can see that the activity is there.

[image]

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Did you initialize leakcanary at application level class? `LeakCanary.install(this);`

Comment: Yes, I think it isn't a LeakCanary problem it is more a Android Studio problem because when I build it on the console everything works fine. Finally I solved it by specifying which Activity Android Studio has to start

Comment: Can you give more details @RalphBergmann?

Comment: In the `Run Configuration` of Android Studio you can select the activity which AS should start

Comment: @RalphBergmann I doubt this may be due to Instant run. Could you disable the Instant run and check.

Comment: For some reason these dependencies work now, when they used to always throw a compile time error that `DisplayLeakActivity does not exist`. 
`debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'`
`releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'`

Comment: since Android Studio v2.2 Preview 4 I can't reproduce it

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me when I try to enable LeakCanary in my app.

Somehow in my Manifest I defined:

```
<application
    android:name="sg.swiftninja.DriverApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    tools:node="replace"  // <-- THIS
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I think the problem is with `tools:node="replace"` in my application tag.

I fixed this by replacing:

```
tools:node="replace"
```

with

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup" // or whatever nodes like this tools:replace="icon, label"
```

Or simply remove the line if you don't need it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Notice this

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/leak_canary_LeakCanary.Base"
    android:name=".internal.DisplayLeakActivity"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:taskAffinity="com.squareup.leakcanary"
    >

</activity>
```

The problem is DisplayLeakActivity's android:enable is false by default. You need to call `LeakCanary.install(this)` in the onCreate() method of Application class.
This sample code is from [LeakCanary documentation](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it but it doesn't help

Comment: Did you reference to your Application class in the Manifest ?

Comment: the setup is complete and correct, I think it is an Android Studio problem